# Animated form, how to check input value on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which uses dynamic styling. Consider this html

```
    <div class="field-name field-form-item">
        <label class="placeholder" for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
    </div>
```

The label is ABOVE the input, with CSS. When you click the label :

```
$('.placeholder').on('click focus', function() {
    $(this).addClass('ph-activated');
    $(this).siblings('input').focus();
})
```

Then the label is animated and let the user type in the input.

If the user dont wan't to write anything, the animation goes back, and hide input field :

```
$('input').on(' blur', function(){
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('ph-activated');
    }
});
```

That's alright.

But when a user fill the input, THEN refresh the page and its browser didn't reset input fields(ie firefox) : the label is above the input, even if the latter is not empty.

I tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('input').val().length) {
        $(this).siblings('label').addClass('ph-activated');
    }
})
```

But it doesn't seem to trigger, I tried several ways to write this function. Up to now I never managed to give the class `ph-activated` to a label with a filled input on page refresh.

Sorry I can't fiddle this. I just have far too much html/css/js/php to copy paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are targeting wrong `element` in `$(document).ready` because you are referring `label` with `this` thinking that `$(this)` is `input` whereas it is `document`. So try applying below code and I hope there will be multiple `input`  elements in page, so I've used `$.each` and looping through all the `inputs`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').each(function(){ //loop through each inputs
        if ($(this).val().length) { 
            $(this).siblings('label').addClass('ph-activated');
        }
    });
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gwrpm3yn/1/)** - Inspect the `label` and you will find `ph-activated` class added to `label`

Comment: Happens @topleft.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var length = $('input').filter(function( index ) {
      return ($(this).val() !== '');
    }).length;

    if (length > 0) {
        $(this).siblings('label').addClass('ph-activated');
    }
})
```

Comment: `$(this)` inside `length>0` condition refers to `document context` not `input context` so you won't get `label` here... :)